# The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a TypeError

Tags: python, pymongo

I am new to python, I am trying to add data into a collection:

```
import pymongo 
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client['inventory']
collection = db['items']

class Inventory():

     def insert(self, data):
        response = collection.insert_one(data)
        return response.inserted_id
```

However I keep getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vitor/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vitor/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/vitor/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/vitor/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2130, in make_response
    " {rv.__class__.__name__}.".format(rv=rv)
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a TypeError.
```

I believe the solution is simple, but I can't seem to find it. I wold appreciate any help.

EDIT:

On request of `amanb`, here are my routes and index.

index:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from src.routes.inventory import inventory_route

app.register_blueprint(inventory_route, url_prefix='/inventory')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

routes:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from src.controllers.inventory import inventoryController

controller = inventoryController()

inventory_route = Blueprint('inventory_route', __name__)

@inventory_route.route("/addItem", methods=['POST'])
def addItem():
    response = controller.addItem()
    return response
```

Comment: The error appears to originate from one of the Flask routes. Can you share the Flask views/routes?

Comment: Here it is, I've tested the route yesterday and it worked fine, but when i added the logic to insert data on database, this error appeared.

Comment: There is no definition for `inventoryController()` and can you explain why `addItem()` is used in line `response = controller.addItem()`? Shouldn't you call `insert()` instead?

Comment: the structure of my project is `index > route > controller > model > database` it is only on `database` that the `insert()` is called. But I managed to solve, like I said it was simple, I am felling pretty dumb. But anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of more tries, I've discovered that the data being passed was wrong for some reason. I was using **Insomnia** to pass data but for some mysterious reason the data inside the request body was giving this error. I just hard codded the data into the `insert_one()` method and it worked.

```
response = collection.insert_one({ "name": "new Item" })
```